# For-loop countdown doesn't work

Tags: c#

how do i make a Countdown with a for loop in an console.application that counts from 0 to -10 in steps of 2 so it counts 0,-2,-4,-6,-8-10.
What I tried was :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        for(int i = 0; i == -10;i = i-2)
        {
            Console.Write("{0,2}", i = i-2);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Countdown End");
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i >= -10;i = i-2)`

Comment: "Console.Write("{0,2}", i = i-2);" I'm sure this does not do what you think it does.

Comment: I would also use `Console.Write("{0,2}", i);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        for(int i = 0; i >= -10; i -= 2)
        {
            Console.Write("{0,2}", i);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Countdown End");
    }
}
```

I changed both the loop conditions and the Console.WriteLine because it was changing the value of i as well.

Comment: Thank you, this is bretty useful

Answer (score 1):

Reconsider your code and what you really want to archieve

```
for(int i = 0; i >= -10;i = i-2) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(i); //i already has the value you want to print
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
Console.WriteLine("Countdown End");
```

If you go for

```
Console.Write("{0}", i = i-2);
```

you calculate `i = i - 2(loop counter) - 2(WriteLine calculation)` per loop, except for the first, where `i` will be `Console.WriteLine("{0}", i = 0 - 2);`

Answer (score 0):

Your expression in the middle of the for loop is false at the beginning. 
The for loop will only function as long as the statement is true.

Change

```
i == -10
```

to

```
i != -10
```

**Edit:**

You should try

```
i > -10
```

just to be on the save(r) side.

**Edit2:** (Credits to user1666620)

```
Console.Write("{0,2}", i = i-2);
```

changes the value of `i` so you should use

```
Console.Write("{0,2}", i-2);
```

instead.
Or just use

```
Console.Write("{0,2}", i);
```

if this is the value you want.

Comment: this could lead to a infinite loop if `i` is never equal to -10. in the given circumstances, then yes, it could work. but if the logic changed?

Comment: @user1666620: I edited a saver condition to the answer.

Comment: @user1666620 Every solution is wrong given "what if developer will make a mistake" argument.

Comment: @BartoszKP tbh if the OP changed only the code in the loop and not in the body, then this answer would have resulted in an infinite loop (`i` is subtracted in the body of the if statment).

Comment: @user1666620 Good point, you're right.

Comment: @user1666620: Now I got it.^^

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i >= -10; i -= 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
}
```

Comment: So you are basically posting the [comment of Eser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068373/for-loop-countdown-doesnt-work#comment52033855_32068373) as an answer?

Comment: @UweKeim so is everyone else. though this isn't a particularly useful answer since it doesn't explain what is wrong with the OP's code.